# Do nodes lose connectivity if no network activity is happening?

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, node-discovery, discovery-protocol

I have a private blockchain that seems to work great, but over 18 hours, the nodes stop talking to each other, no matter how many I start with.  So they go from 25/25 connections to 0.

Something I don't have is any real work being done on the network.  There are miners, but nothing substantial to mine since I'm not deploying any contracts.

Could this lack of real work be the reason the nodes lose connectivity?  It's not a networking problem.  The boxes can ping each other.

If it matters, I'm using Parity.